# How to use solr index different type of data?

Tags: solr

I use solr to index json data. The code is below:

```
    curl http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/update -d '
[
 {"id"         : "book2",
  "cat_s"      : "fantasy" ,
  "pubyear_i"  :  2010 ,
  "ISBN_s"     : "978-0-7653-2635-5" 
 }
]'
```

Now, I want to index like CSV, XML or other kinds of data, how can I do it?

Comment: can you post here solr schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add `Content-Type` Parameter in the request Header.**

Content Type Map :

```
--------------------------------
|  Type      |  Value           |
-------------+-------------------
|  xml       | application/xml  |
|------------+------------------|
|  csv       | application/csv  |
|------------+------------------|
|  json      | application/json |
--------------------------------
```

Example for xml :

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/update -d '
<add>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">book2</field>
      <field name="cat_s">fantasy</field>
      <field name="pubyear_i">2010</field>
      <field name="ISBN_s">978-0-7653-2635-5</field>
   </doc>
</add>'
```

More : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers

Comment: Hi bro , for the xml eample , it response                                           Illegal processing instruction ta                                                                             rget ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,5]</str><int name="code">400</int>

Comment: @zechengzhao Updated answer,

Comment: @zechengzhao if the answer is correct you should mark it.